# JQuery fancytree - TypeError: a.ui is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to use the fancytree plugin but am getting the 
following error:
TypeError: a.ui is undefined

associated with the file jquery.fancytree-2.0.0-7/jquery.fancytree-all.min.js

Below is the  contents of the code I am using:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.fancytree-2.0.0-7/skin-win8/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.fancytree-2.0.0-7/jquery.fancytree-all.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

...
</head>
```

Please can you inform me what I need to change / is the problem?

Thank you,
S...

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this before jquery-ui

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Required minimum versions are jQuery 1.7+ and jQuery UI 1.8.6+, as iGuillermo mentioned it looks like you're missing jQuery UI

See https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#getting-started